# Multiple links spilling out of rows

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have created two divs that are used as clickable links however I can't get them to stay side by side. If I use row the two divs only stay side by side when not using the link tag. As soon as the link tag is applied then the divs spill out of the rows. How could I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container col-md-12 pt-5">
    <h1 style="font: Helvetica; font-weight: normal; font-size: 230%">Administrator Control Panel</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="container col-md-12 row" style="height: 140px;">
      <!-- Sports Box -->
      <a href="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div id="Sport" href="" class="col-md-2 h-100 px-0" style="background-color: #167acc; border-radius: 10px;">
          <h3 class="text-white" style="float: left; position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 5%; transform: translate(-10%, -40%); margin:15px;">Sports</h3>
          <p class="text-white" style="float: right; position: absolute; top: 15%; left: 78%; transform: translate(-50%, -10%);">You have</p>
          <h3 class="text-white" style="float: right; position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 83%; transform: translate(-50%, -40%);">18</h3>
          <p class="text-white" style="float: right; position: absolute; top: 63%; left: 81%; transform: translate(-50%, -40%);">Sports</p>
          <div style="background-color: white; border:solid #167acc; border-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-width:1px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%;">
            <p style="float: left; margin:5px; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 75%;">Manage Them</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <!-- Options Box -->
      <a href="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <div class="col-md-2 h-100 px-0" style="margin-left:5px; background-color: #5bba4a; border-radius: 10px;">
        <h3 class="text-white" style="float: left; position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 5%; transform: translate(-10%, -40%); margin:15px;">Options</h3>
        <p class="text-white" style="float: right; position: absolute; top: 15%; left: 78%; transform: translate(-50%, -10%);">You have</p>
        <h3 class="text-white" style="float: right; position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 83%; transform: translate(-50%, -40%);">18</h3>
        <p class="text-white" style="float: right; position: absolute; top: 63%; left: 81%; transform: translate(-50%, -40%);">Options</p>
        <div style="background-color: white; border:solid #5bba4a; border-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-width:1px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%;">
          <p style="float: left; margin:5px; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 75%;">Manage Them</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Current Outcome: [image: Current Outcome]
vs
Desired outcome: [image: Desired outcome]

Comment: You seem to be using tools without having taken the time to read their manuals. Here's [what you need](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). There is a reason why you won't see `container` and `row` classes on the same element anywhere in Bootstrap v4, nor will you ever see `row` and `col-*` classes on the same element, nor a `.container` inside another `.container`.

Comment: Even so, each of the columns within row don't stay on the same line when using a link tag

Comment: Bootstrap allows for very fast prototyping, without having to right much (often any) custom CSS. Have a look at their shiny new [card-styles](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-styles) and [start a-fresh](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/zhkwjurt/)

Comment: Again, not helpful. How do I get links to span within a row

Comment: I apologize for not helping you, Tobias. Enjoy your time learning CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your using bootstrap row and column in a wrong way. `container` is user for block. then you have to create a `row` and then `column`. run the code and view it on full page. Comment if you need any clarification

[Check this link for more info about row and column](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_medium.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container pt-5">
        <h1 style="font: Helvetica; font-weight: normal; font-size: 230%">Administrator Control Panel</h1>
        <hr>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="height: 140px;">
                <!-- Sports Box -->
                <a href="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                    <div id="Sport" href="" class=" h-100 px-0" style="background-color: #167acc; border-radius: 10px;">
                        <h3 class="text-white" style="float: left; position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 5%; transform: translate(-10%, -40%); margin:15px;">Sports</h3>
                        <p class="text-white" style="float: right; position: absolute; top: 15%; left: 78%; transform: translate(-50%, -10%);">You have</p>
                        <h3 class="text-white" style="float: right; position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 83%; transform: translate(-50%, -40%);">18</h3>
                        <p class="text-white" style="float: right; position: absolute; top: 63%; left: 81%; transform: translate(-50%, -40%);">Sports</p>
                        <div style="background-color: white; border:solid #167acc; border-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-width:1px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 92.3%;">
                            <p style="float: left; margin:5px; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 75%;">Manage Them</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="height: 140px;">
                <a href="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                    <div class=" h-100 px-0" style="margin-left:5px; background-color: #5bba4a; border-radius: 10px;">
                        <h3 class="text-white" style="float: left; position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 5%; transform: translate(-10%, -40%); margin:15px;">Options</h3>
                        <p class="text-white" style="float: right; position: absolute; top: 15%; left: 78%; transform: translate(-50%, -10%);">You have</p>
                        <h3 class="text-white" style="float: right; position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 83%; transform: translate(-50%, -40%);">18</h3>
                        <p class="text-white" style="float: right; position: absolute; top: 63%; left: 81%; transform: translate(-50%, -40%);">Options</p>
                        <div style="background-color: white; border:solid #5bba4a; border-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-width:1px; position: absolute; bottom: 0;width: 90.8%;">
                            <p style="float: left; margin:5px; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 75%;">Manage Them</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```